# No Overlay widget found despite Scaffold and MaterialApp

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, riverpod

I'm using `Riverpod` as global state manager on my application; in this case, I'm using it to handle the application's launch: if there is a profile persited on device, it will go directly to one screen based on the user's role, if there is no such profile, it will send us to the login screen.

Given a persisted user I am getting the next bug:
[image]

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building Tooltip("Open navigation menu", dirty, state: _TooltipState#4e2ac(ticker inactive)):
No Overlay widget found.

Tooltip widgets require an Overlay widget ancestor for correct operation.

The most common way to add an Overlay to an application is to include a MaterialApp or Navigator widget in the runApp() call.

The specific widget that failed to find an overlay was: Tooltip
  "Open navigation menu"
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AppBar file:///home/luisalaguna/Projects/thesis_cancer/lib/core/presentation/widgets/header.dart:17:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Overlay.of.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:306:9)
#1      Overlay.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:309:6)
#2      _TooltipState.build (package:flutter/src/material/tooltip.dart:457:20)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4612:27)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4495:15)
```

Header is an **AppBar** widget; this bug would not be strange if all the widget wouldn't be wrapped by an **Scaffold** and a **MaterialApp** widgets:
[image]

The code on main file is [this](https://github.com/SalahAdDin/thesis_cancer/blob/user-state-provider/lib/main.dart):

```
class CancerApp extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _appRouter = AppRouter();
    final bool darkTheme = useProvider(darkThemeProvider);
    final launcherState = useProvider(launcherProvider);

    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);

    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Thesis Cancer',
      theme: darkTheme ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
      routerDelegate: _appRouter.delegate(),
      routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
      // home: SplashScreen()
      builder: (context, router) => launcherState.when(
          loading: () => SplashScreen(),
          needsProfile: () => LoginPage(),
          profileLoaded: () => MainScreen()),
    );
  }
}
```

About the launcher notifier, you can see it [here](https://github.com/SalahAdDin/thesis_cancer/blob/user-state-provider/lib/core/application/launcher/launcher.notifier.dart).

After rafactoring this workflow I am getting this bug, i didn't get it when the `profileLoaded` state was returning the user(I was getting another issue).

What can be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Add `applyElevationOverlayColor: true,` on your Theme